# Overwrite the url function of a specific node entity

Tags: 8, nodes

Can I overwrite the url function of a specific content type of node entity ?
 So to have a different pattern when i use: $node->url();

Answer (score 1):

**Entity URI callback**

You can implement an URI callback. Example in *comment.module*:

```
/**
 * Entity URI callback.
 */
function comment_uri(CommentInterface $comment) {
  return new Url(
    'entity.comment.canonical',
    [
      'comment' => $comment->id(),
    ],
    ['fragment' => 'comment-' . $comment->id()]
  );
}
```

and add the callback to the annotations of the entity type:

```
*   uri_callback = "comment_uri",
```

For an existing entity use a [hook_entity_type_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_alter/8.3.x).

**Bundle specific URI callback**

A URI callback for a specific content type can be defined in the bundle definitions:

```
**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_bundle_info_alter(&$bundles) {
  if (isset($bundles['node']['my_content_type'])) {
    $bundles['node']['my_content_type']['uri_callback'] = 'my_content_type_uri';
  }
}
```

The callback:

```
/**
 * Bundle URI callback.
 */
function my_content_type_uri(NodeInterface $node) {
  // build a url object $url
  return $url;
}
```

A bundle-specific callback takes precedence over the generic one for the entity type and a link template (defined in the links array of the entity type) takes precedence over both, so you need to remove the link template if you want to override an existing one, e.g. `canonical`, which makes you responsible to provide the route needed for the custom url, if it was built before by a route provider and is not defined in a *.routing.yml file.

---

**Edit:**

To modify the url in links to a specific content type you can use a [hook_link_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.4.x):

```
function mymodule_link_alter(&$variables) {
  $url = $variables['url'];
  if ($url->isRouted() && $url->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
    if (isset($variables['options']['entity'])) {
      $node = $variables['options']['entity'];
      if ($node->bundle() == 'article') {
        // modify the links to articles
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I understand how the code works, but how does the mentioned uri callback of the comment module gets called for canonical urls, when the comment entity has a link template defined?

Comment: Indeed the uri callback in the comment module does not run during normal operation of the site. comment::permalink() adds the fragment instead.

Comment: ! Don't work:

  function commerce_entity_bundle_info_alter(&$bundles) {
    if (isset($bundles['node']['product_display'])) {
      $bundles['node']['product_display']['uri_callback'] = 'product_display_uri';
    }
  }


  function product_display_uri(NodeInterface $node) {
    return Url::fromRoute('my.route');
  }

$node->url(); get canonical url @4k4

Comment: This is the problem I've described. If you use url() without parameter you get the canonical link and this will be returned according to the link template  in the entity definition.

Comment: I would like to overwrite the method, so that the views (for example, content) automatically have the new url. What do you advise ?

Comment: You can use a hook_link_alter(), see edit.

Comment: This is incorrect. If i use $node->link() i have correct url generated by: mymodule_link_alter but if i use $node->url the hook does not work. Please, u know a specific hook for ->url() ?

Comment: The original question was about the entity level. Then you've asked in the comment before about links in views and I tried to help with an approach to overwrite the url for a specific content type on this level. Of course this happens later than the url() method of the entity.

Comment: So what would you recommend?

Comment: If you can use a custom link relation instead of canonical in url(), then it's easy to implement a bundle specific callback as described. For the canonical link template it is theoretically possible, but there are a lot of things that can go wrong. So I would look for another approach, like the one for view links.

Comment: I solved using the function: -> toUrl () and using a non-existent "$ ref", so read the uri_callback

Comment: But in this way I can not define more uri_callback for bundle
 :(

Comment: I have an example of a bundle specific uri callback for one node bundle with a fallback for all the other bundles: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246712/45409